# Load JSON File on the server side in GWT

Tags: gwt, tomcat

I have a GWT application and I load a .json file on the server side like this:

```
InputStream source = new FileInputStream(testFile.json);
```

This works perfectly when I start the application directly in eclipse. However, when I deploy the app on tomcat, it does not work. It seems like, that the application  is looking for that file in the bin folder of tomcat (???). However, the correct path would be tomcat/webapps/myProject/testFile.json.

Does anyone know how to get the correct path (without harcoding it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileInputStream` locates files depending on the current working directory, which in turn depends on the way how you started the application, which in turn is thus not controllable from inside your application. In case of web applications, you need [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `FileInputStream` to obtain web application's own resources. It takes a path which is relative to the web content folder.

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/testfile.json");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Comment: do you mean with 'servletContext' the file name of the class calling the getResourceAsStream(..) function?

Comment: No, it's the `ServletContext` class. See also the `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()` link in my answer. In a class which extends from `Servlet`, it's available by the inherited `getServletContext()` method.

Comment: So, if your servlet class extends from [`RemoteServiceServlet`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet.html) then you should be able to get it by `getServletContext()`.

Comment: what if I need the path in a class which does not inherit from RemoteServiceServlet? I don't want to pass the ServletContext through all method calls. Just instantiate a new RemoteServiceServlet in another class seems to be pretty wrong :s

Comment: I don't do GWT, but Google teaches me that Spring is very helpful in providing this information by an interface. As a completely different alternative, you can also just drop that file in the classpath (surely if it is never requested without intervention of a GWT servlet) so that you can just get it from context's class loader.

Comment: hmm... well I tried it this way: Class.class.getResourceAsStream("test.json"); but this works also only fine when I run it in eclipse...

Comment: In web applications, you must use the thread's context class loader. See also the "See also" link in my answer.